# PHP: Deal with delimiters in dynamic regular expression

Tags: php, regex

Let's say I want to create a PHP tool to dynamically check a string against regular expression pattern. There is one problem with that: delimiters.

I would like to be able to do the following (simplified example):

```
$pattern = $_POST['pattern'];
$matched = (preg_match($pattern, $_POST['string']) === 1);
```

I don't want the users to put delimiters in the input, just a pure pattern, like `^a[bc]+d`. How to deal with delimiters? I could do this:

```
$pattern = '/' . $_POST['pattern'] . '/';
```

Or with any other possible delimiter, but what about escaping? Is placing `\` before each character in the pattern, being the same one as the delimiter of my choice, enough? Like this:

```
$pattern = '/' . str_replace('/', '\\/', $_POST['pattern']) . '/';
```

What is a neat way to deal with delimiters?

Comment: What's the problem with what you're doing?

Comment: I'm afraid there might be some edge case I'm not aware of.

Comment: I think it's fine.  With all due respect, voting to close here as there is no actual problem and afaik the thing you've done is pretty much exactly as it should be.

Comment: only comment i would make at all is that you don't need strict comparison on preg_match, you can just do `$matched = preg_match($pattern, $_POST['string'])` and it will return either true or false

Comment: I know. I prefer to use `===` for the most part though, to remember what the functions are returning. My question is one from "am I doing it right?" family. To be honest, I asked for educational purpose only.

Comment: Yes, you are doing it right — by that I'm referring to the last part of your question which concatenates the delimiter with a replacement on the pattern.  You can stress test this all you want and it should be fine.

Comment: This assumes of course that if a user submits `/test123/` as input, the slashes should be treated as part of the pattern and *not* delimiters, and they are not to be removed.  If you want to assume that they *are* delimiters and remove them then you should use @Ibu's answer which seems reasonable. But you've made it relatively clear that you don't want to sanitize the input, so I'm assuming the former

Comment: You are right, if somebody types `/test123/`, I'm assuming he wants the `/`'s to be the part of the actual content. Delimiters are just mechanics of PHP's regex, I don't consider them as any pattern standard. My biggest doubt about this entire thing was that maybe it's better to use asymmetric delimiters here, like `{` and `}`. Maybe it would make the necessary escaping safer? Not sure how it affects the behavior of syntactic curly braces.

Comment: maybe - if you haven't already you can read up on php's PCRE regex implementation here: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php I think you'll be fine either way

Comment: On second thought, I think that maybe asymmetric will be actually worse in this case, because I'd want to escape the literals, but don't escape the syntactic ones, right? And delimiters like `/` or `~` or `#` are always just literals.

Answer (score -1):

You have to check the input to identify the delimiter if there is any and remove it. This way if the user follows the rules, you don't have to worry, but if they don't the delimiter is removed anyway. The delimiter can be identified by comparing the first and last character.

```
// with incorrect input.
$input = "/^a[bc]+d/"; // from $_POST['pattern']
$delim = "/";
if ($input[0] === $input[strlen($input) - 1]) {
    $delim = $input[0];
}
$sInput = str_replace($delim,"",$input);
echo $sInput; // ^a[bc]+d
```

With correct input, you don't have to worry.

```
$input = "^a[bc]+d"; // from $_POST['pattern']
$delim = "/";
if ($input[0] === $input[strlen($input) - 1]) {
    $delim = $input[0];
}
$sInput = str_replace($delim,"",$input);
echo $sInput; // ^a[bc]+d
```

`$sInput` is your sanitized pattern. You can use it directly  to test your string.

$matched = (preg_match($sInput, $_POST['string']) === 1);

Comment: This is not what my question is about.

Comment: `I don't want the users to put delimiters in the input`

Comment: Yes, even if the user puts delimiters, this removes it.

Comment: First of all, it doesn't answer my question. Second of all, why would you use `preg_replace` for such a simple thing instead of just `str_replace('/', '', $input)`? It does the same thing in this case.

Comment: See my updated answer. The delimiter can be custom, ex: `~`. You can detect the delimter, and use preg replace or str_replace to remove it.

Comment: I don't want to sanitize any input. Users are asked to type a pattern, without delimiters. Not sure about all different regex engines, but the only one I have used that is using delimiters this way, is PHP's. Delimiters are not a part of all regular expression standards and I don't want them in my tool. It's just that I'm using PHP to develop this tool, so I need to deal with the delimiters to match.